# Good file copy or transfer tool for win vista/7

Tags: windows-vista, filesystems, crash, file-transfer

An SSD drive crashed on a win7 x64 machine.  So I brought it over to my win vista machine and tried to drag a particular folder over.  But there are some files that give strange errors or restart windows (not the OS, just all the icons and background and windows disappear and then reappear with an error message and the file transfer aborts) when attempted to transfer.  Since I have thousands of folders with many files each, it's too difficult to figure it all out manually.

Is there a tool which will try to move every single file and report which ones it couldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php), but there are others.

The description:

> TeraCopy is a compact program designed to copy and move files at the maximum possible speed, providing the user with a lot of features:
>
> - **Copy files faster.** TeraCopy uses dynamically adjusted buffers to reduce seek times. Asynchronous copy speeds up file transfer between two physical hard drives.
> - **Pause and resume file transfers.** Pause copy process at any time to free up system resources and continue with a single click.
> - **Error recovery.** In case of copy error, TeraCopy will try several times and in the worse case just skip the file, not terminating the entire transfer.
> - **Interactive file list.** TeraCopy shows failed file transfers and lets you fix the problem and recopy only problem files.
> - **Shell integration.** TeraCopy can completely replace Explorer copy and move functions, allowing you work with files as usual.
> - **Full Unicode support.**
> - **Windows 7 x64 support.**

Link current as of 7/22/13

Comment: the link is broken...

Comment: @tinmaru it works fine for me... http://codesector.com/teracopy/

Comment: very strange... I have no response from the codesector.com name server... I changed my DNS to google's 8.8.8.8 and now it works!

Comment: @tinmaru if you don't mind, could you please take away your downvote?

Comment: yes sorry but I had to wait 8h between two vote for the same question: I vote you up in the end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You describe Windows Explorer crashing, which means it's trying to identify the files as it's copying them. This is not helpful, obviously.

Get your hands on [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/). It will let you copy the folders and not worry about the files' formats.

If you use the Sync feature, it will show you which files aren't being copied across.

Just remember to run it as an Administrator to bypass any permission problems.